# Checking for Undefined In React

Tags: reactjs, components, redux, undefined

I have a scenario where I'm passing data from a reducer into my react state.

data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test",
    "content": {
        "body": "sdfsdf"
        "image": "http://example.com"
    }
}
```

Using componentWillRecieveProps, this works perfectly for retrieving the title.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        title: nextProps.blog.title,
    })
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty retrieving the nested fields. When I do this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("new title is", nextProps.blog.title);
    console.log("new body content is", nextProps.blog.content["body"]);
    this.setState({
        title: nextProps.blog.title,
        body: nextProps.blog.content["body"]
    })
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

The error of an undefined body goes away after I click the debugger and the content is loaded. Is there anyway I can combat this issue?

I tried to check for undefined like this:

```
if (typeof nextProps.blog.content["body"] != 'undefined'){
```

But this doesn't work either and I believe it's because the blog is undefined.

Comment: I Think your mistake is that your "body" is nested inside the "content"

Comment: @naomi thanks! I fixed my code to blog.content instead of just content, is that what you meant? I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you can do is check whether you props is defined initially or not by checking if `nextProps.blog.content` is undefined or not since your body is nested inside it like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(nextProps.blog.content !== undefined && nextProps.blog.title !== undefined) {
       console.log("new title is", nextProps.blog.title);
       console.log("new body content is", nextProps.blog.content["body"]);
       this.setState({
           title: nextProps.blog.title,
           body: nextProps.blog.content["body"]
       })
    }
}
```

You need not use type to check for undefined, just the strict operator `!==` which compares the value by their type as well as value

In order to check for undefined, you can also use the `typeof` operator like

```
typeof nextProps.blog.content != "undefined"
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was putting undefined in quotations. This did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem . Happy to help

Answer (score 21):

I was face same problem ..... And I got solution by using `typeof()`

```
if (typeof(value) !== 'undefined' && value != null) {
         console.log('Not Undefined and Not Null')
  } else {
         console.log('Undefined or Null')
}
```

You must have to use `typeof()` to identified `undefined`

Comment: Why you give down vote can you make a comment with perfect reason ?

Comment: because OR is wrong here ! It should be AND. We want : not undefined AND not null. Both should be true.

Comment: Thanks to @Tom identified my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

In case you also need to check if `nextProps.blog` is not `undefined` ; you can do that in a single `if` statement, like this:

```
if (typeof nextProps.blog !== "undefined" && typeof nextProps.blog.content !== "undefined") {
    //
}
```

And, when an `undefined` , `empty` or `null` value is not expected; you can make it more concise:

```
if (nextProps.blog && nextProps.blog.content) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding a question mark as below. This worked for me.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        title: nextProps?.blog?.title,
        body: nextProps?.blog?.content
     })
    }
```

Comment: Note: before using, check whether your environment supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score -4):

You can check undefined object using below code.

> ReactObject === 'undefined'

Comment: Type of  `undefined` is `undefined` not `String`.