# Redux State Problem : TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to react native and redux especialy and I got an error message that I really struggle to deal with.

**This is the error im getting**

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0,
> _reactRedux.useSelector)(function (state) {
> return state.myPigeons.myPigeons;
> }).length')

I will show you here all my related code I got so far and after that explain what my intention behind all this is.

**MainScreen.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native'; 
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import CustomButton from '../components/CustomButton';
import CustomPigeonPicker from '../components/CustomPigeonsPicker';
import { addPigeon } from '../store/actions/pigeon';


const MainScreen = props =>{
    dispatch = useDispatch();
    const availablePigeons = (useSelector(state => state.myPigeons.myPigeons)).length;
    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.tophalf}>
                <CustomPigeonPicker style={styles.pigeonpicker}
                    placeholder={`You have so many pigeons: ${availablePigeons}`}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottomhalf}>
                <CustomButton 
                    style={styles.button} 
                    onPress={() => dispatch(addPigeon)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen:{
        flexDirection: "column",
        flex: 1
    },
    button:{
        fontFamily: "AmaticBold",
        //Ab hier Einstellungen zum Schatten
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.34,
        shadowRadius: 6,
        elevation: 3.5,
        width: "30%",
    },
    tophalf:{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    bottomhalf:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    pigeonpicker:{
    
    }
});

export default MainScreen;
```

**pigeon.js (action)**

```
export const ADD_PIGEON = 'ADD_PIGEON';

export const addPigeon = () => {
    return {type: ADD_PIGEON}
};
```

**pigeon.js (reducer)**

```
import {ALLPIGEONS} from '../../data/pigeons_data';
import { ADD_PIGEON } from '../actions/pigeon';


const initialPigeonState = () => {
    myPigeons = []
};

const pigeonReducer = (state = initialPigeonState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PIGEON:{
            var generatedPigeon = Math.floor(Math.random() * ALLPIGEONS.length);
            generatedPigeon.nickname = "Kuba";
            var updatedPigeons = [...state.myPigeons, generatedPigeon]
            return{...state, myPigeons: updatedPigeons}
        }
    };
    return state;
};

export default pigeonReducer;
```

**pigeons_data.js**

```
import pigeon from '../models/pigeon';

const ALLPIGEONS = [
    new pigeon(
        1,
        "red",
        "Red-billed pigeon",
        " "
    ),
    new pigeon(
        2,
        "blue",
        "Blue pigeon",
        " "
    ),
    new pigeon(
        3,
        "white",
        "Release dove",
        " "
    ),
    new pigeon(
        4,
        "brown",
        "Brown cuckoo-dove",
        " "
    ),
    new pigeon(
        5,
        "green",
        "Green pigeon",
        " "
    ),
];

export default ALLPIGEONS;
```

**App.js**

```
//Automatic imports
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

//My imports
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

//import other screens
import PBNavigator from './navigation/PBNavigator';

//import Reducers
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';
import pigeonReducer from './store/reducers/pigeon';

//Loading Fonts, returns promise
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'Magnus' : require('./assets/fonts/MagnusText.ttf'),
    'AmaticBold' : require('./assets/fonts/Amatic-Bold.ttf'),
    'AmaticRegular' : require('./assets/fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf'),
    'SEASRN' : require('./assets/fonts/SEASRN.ttf'),
  });
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  myPigeons: pigeonReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function App() {
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false); //are fonts loaded?

  if(!dataLoaded){ //will go into if clause because fonts are not loaded
    return(
      <AppLoading 
        startAsync={fetchFonts} 
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    )
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PBNavigator/>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The problem here is basicly that I want to have a state in redux where all my pigeons I have are stored (my state should be empty right now because I did not add any pigeon to my state) and after I click the button in Mainscreen.js I add a pigeon to the state so that the text can display how many pigeons I have.

Right now the app is always crashing when I make my way to the MainScreen. I am thankfull for any help!

**EDIT: My PBNavigator File** (that was requested):

```
//All modules that needs to be implemented
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

//All imported screens from my screens folder
import ChatScreen from '../screens/ChatScreen';
import ContactsScreen from '../screens/ContactsScreen';
import MainScreen from '../screens/MainScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import PigeonBaseScreen from '../screens/PigeonBaseScreen';
import PigeonLexiconScreen from '../screens/PigeonLexiconScreen';
import ShopScreen from '../screens/ShopScreen';

//Importing other recources 
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

//Setting up stack navigator
const PBNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            headerShown: false,
        }
    },
    Chat: ChatScreen,
    Contacts: ContactsScreen,
    PigeonBase: PigeonBaseScreen,
    PigeonLexicon: PigeonLexiconScreen,
    Shop: ShopScreen
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
        backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
    },
    headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
    
    }
);

const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Auth:{
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            headerShown: false,
        }
    } 
});

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: AuthNavigator, //LoginScreen you cant go back after you passed it
    Homescreen: PBNavigator //switching so PBNavigator when you finished authentification
});





export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: You can check the details in below link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735406/checking-for-undefined-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735406/checking-for-undefined-in-react)

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735406/checking-for-undefined-in-react) You can get the idea from this also.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks wrong

```js
var generatedPigeon = Math.floor(Math.random() * ALLPIGEONS.length);
generatedPigeon.nickname = "Kuba";
```

Try more like

```js
var generatedPigeonNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * ALLPIGEONS.length);
var generatedPigeon= ALLPIGEONS[generatedPigeonNo];
generatedPigeon.nickname = "Kuba";
```

Comment: Im sorry but this did not help me, the same error is still there

Comment: Im pretty sure it has something to do with redux and how I try to access the store data, I just dont know what Im doing wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

state.myPigeons in main.js is undefined at the time of starting the application. If you are trying to perform some action on a redux object, the value should be defined in there. The best approach is to always have a defensive check in the code to check the object is not 'undefined'.

Comment: Sounds like a possible explanation for my problem. Do you have a suggestion how I can define it as soon as the application starts and if so, in which components it would be the best? Basicly I want to have an existing initialState of my pigeon reducer so that I can read its value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735406/checking-for-undefined-in-react

Comment: Im sorry but this did not help me either. As I understand I already have a Initial State in my reducer which should be also set because I pass it into my pigeonReducer as my default state, therefore I still cant figure out what exactly is causing this error.

Comment: I even checked several tutorials on youtube that cover redux state management and I dont understand why my code is throwing and error in any way. Like I said, Im really new to this topics and still not quite skilled.

Comment: in order to diagnose can you comment out the line which it is complaining about : state.myPigeons.myPigeons. Instead print the value inside the state : state.myPigeons.myPigeons.

Comment: Well I tried console.log(getState(state.myPigeons.myPigeons)); but also I tried out console.log(state.myPigeons.myPigeons); and both commands failed. The error I got is "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getState" or rather "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: state". It looks like the the component itself has no access to the store or better said the redux state, but that cant be really the case because in PBNavigator.js and App.js I connected the Provider with the main navigator and so every component, no matter if navigator or just a plain js file, should be able to access the data.

Comment: I have never used useSelector() hook myself to render redux value to the component. Rather have used mapStateToProps like this example here : https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/easy-redux-b29391b499cb. It is clean and easy approach.

Just for reference, I was reading a bit about using hooks like useSelector in here : https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: to help debug this, you should log the entire state object, then you can see straight off what is null and what is not

Answer (score 1):

Where do you declare MainScreen ? In PB navigator?

Comment: Well yes, MainScreen is part of my StackNavigator which itself is a part of my Switch Navigator. I appended at the end the PBNavigator file so you can have a look inside on how I set up my navigation.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still trying to figure out the problem in the given code, i think i got it;

```
const initialPigeonState = () => {
    myPigeons = []
};
```

This is the whole problem. Here `initialPigeonState` is defined as a function which does not return any thing. Thus causing error.

Now to get rid of the error, we can either define `initialPigeonState` as;

```
initialPigeonState = {
    myPigeons: []
}
```

Or if you want to keep it as a function, then return an object from it;

```
const initialPigeonState = () => ({
    myPigeons: []
});
```

Parenthesis after the arrow notation means `return` and then what is inside it is returned (here an object).