# React Formik automatically giving me error whenever I write in a field

Tags: reactjs, formik, reactstrap

I have the following functional component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Row, FormGroup,Label,Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import axios from "axios";

const addSlidersUrl = "anApiUrl";

const validateSliderSlug = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider Slug value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderImage = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider Image value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderEnText = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider En Text value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderArText = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider Ar Text value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderEnButtonText = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider En Button Text value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderArButtonText = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider Ar Button Text value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderEnButtonLink = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider En Button Link value";
    }
    return error;
}
const validateSliderArButtonLink = (value) => {
    let error;
    if(!value){
        error="Please enter a Slider Ar Button Link value";
    }
    return error;
}

const AddSlider = (props) => {

    const ontNewSliderSubmit = (values) => {
        if( values.sliderSlug !== '' && values.sliderImage !== '' && values.sliderEnText !== '' && values.sliderArText !== '' && values.sliderEnButtonText !== '' && values.sliderArButtonText !== '' && values.sliderEnButtonLink !== '' && values.sliderArButtonLink !== ''){
            axios.post(
                addSlidersUrl,
                {
                    adminid: props.adminid,
                    token: props.adminlogintoken,
                    slider_slug: values.sliderSlug,
                    slider_image: values.sliderImage,
                    slider_en_text: values.sliderEnText,
                    slider_ar_text: values.sliderArText,
                    slider_en_button_text: values.sliderEnButtonText,
                    slider_ar_button_text: values.sliderArButtonText,
                    slider_en_button_link: values.sliderEnButtonLink,
                    slider_ar_button_link: values.sliderArButtonlink,
                }
            )
            .then(
                res => console.log(res)
            )
            .catch(
                err => console.log(err)
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <Row>
            <Card>
                <div style={{ width: "90%", marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}>
                    <Row style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        Add A New Slider
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Formik onSubmit={ontNewSliderSubmit}>
                            {({ errors}) => (
                                <Form>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderSlug">
                                           Slider Slug:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderSlug"
                                            validate={validateSliderSlug}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderSlug && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderSlug}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderImage">
                                           Slider Image:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderImage"
                                            validate={validateSliderImage}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderImage && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderImage}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderEnText">
                                           Slider En Text:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderEnText"
                                            validate={validateSliderEnText}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderEnText && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderEnText}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderArText">
                                           Slider Ar Text:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderArText"
                                            validate={validateSliderArText}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderArText && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderArText}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderEnButtonText">
                                           Slider En Button Text:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderEnButtonText"
                                            validate={validateSliderEnButtonText}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderEnText && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderEnButtonText}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderArButtonText">
                                           Slider Ar Button Text:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderArButtonText"
                                            validate={validateSliderArButtonText}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderArButtonText && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderArButtonText}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderEnButtonlink">
                                           Slider En Button Link:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderEnButtonLink"
                                            validate={validateSliderEnButtonLink}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderEnButtonLink && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderEnButtonLink}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                                        <Label for="sliderArButtonLink">
                                           Slider Ar Button Link:
                                        </Label>
                                        <Field
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="sliderArButtonLink"
                                            validate={validateSliderArButtonLink}
                                        />
                                        {errors.sliderArButtonLink && (
                                            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                                {errors.sliderArButtonLink}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <div style={ {display:"flex",flexDirection:"row",alignItems:"center",width:"50%",justifyContent:"space-between"} }>
                                            <Button
                                                color="success"
                                                type="submit"
                                            >
                                                Add Slider
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button
                                                color="danger"
                                                type="button"
                                                onClick={props.cancelAddingItem}
                                            >
                                                Cancel
                                            </Button>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            )}
                        </Formik>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </Card>
        </Row>
    );
}

export default AddSlider;
```

It's just a simple component that has a `formik` which should allow me to fill in the fields and when pressing the `Add Slider` button it should validate that I didn't leave any field empty before executing a function. The problem is that as soon as I type in any field I receive the following 2 errors and I cannot understand why:

[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNx3a.png)

[second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFmTW.png)

Edit: Note that I'm getting the error as soon as I type 1 letter in any of the fields not after i press the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

SliderEnText is **undefined** - you checking for empty string right now:

```
values.sliderArButtonText !== ''
```

try for undefined:

[Checking for Undefined In React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735406/checking-for-undefined-in-react)

Comment: but i'm getting the error as soon as I type 1 letter in the field, not after i click the submit button...why is that?